# How to read .nlp file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node-nlp module like below.

```
const { NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');

const manager = new NlpManager({ languages: ['en'] });
// Adds the utterances and intents for the NLP
manager.addDocument('en', 'goodbye for now', 'greetings.bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'bye bye take care', 'greetings.bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'okay see you later', 'greetings.bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'bye for now', 'greetings.bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i must go', 'greetings.bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'hello', 'greetings.hello');
manager.addDocument('en', 'hi', 'greetings.hello');
manager.addDocument('en', 'howdy', 'greetings.hello');

// Train also the NLG
manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.bye', 'Till next time');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.bye', 'see you soon!');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.hello', 'Hey there!');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.hello', 'Greetings!');

// Train and save the model.
(async() => {
    await manager.train();
    manager.save("./model.nlp", true);
    const response = await manager.process('en', 'I should go now');
    console.log(response);
})();
```

This codes make 'model.nlp' file and works well. 
But I want to this 'model.nlp' file repeatedly without train and save again in the other js file.
How can I read model.nlp file and use this with '.process()?
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');

const data = fs.readFileSync('model.nlp', 'utf8');
const manager = new NlpManager();
manager.import(data);
```

Source: https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/master/docs/v3/nlp-manager.md#importexport